# SAS reference line over chart

Tags: graph, sas

I want to plot daily sales figures versus day of month.

```
data _test3;
input day dailysales dow $5. weeklysales;
cards;
1 20.1 Mon 19.2
2 19.0 Tue 19.2
....
30 32.1 Tue 30.0
31 33.3  Wed 30.0
;
run;
```

Without grouping `dow(day of week)`, this code works

```
proc sgplot data=_test3 ;
vbar Day / response=DailySale barwidth=0.7 nooutline;
vline Day / response=WeeklySale;
keylegend / position=topright noborder autoitemsize;
xaxis display=(nolabel);
yaxis grid;
run;
```

This plots daily sales with weekly average as reference lines over bars.

But I need different color for different day of week. e.g red on `Sun` and `pink` on `Mon` etc.

so I adjust the above code.

```
proc sgplot data=_test3 ;
vbar Day / group = dow response=DailySale barwidth=0.7 nooutline;
vline Day / group = dow WeeklySale;
keylegend / position=topright noborder autoitemsize;
xaxis display=(nolabel);
yaxis grid;
run;
```

For the reference line (weekly sale), I don't want to group it by `dow`. Ideally it should be a  black line overlays the bars. But SAS has to keep `group` in the `vline` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only group by one variable for summarized plots (ie, a plot where SAS is being asked to summarize things).  However, you don't actually have a summarized plot here I don't think.  You have already done the work (dailysales and weeklysales), and just need to plot it.  So use the non summarized versions of the plots; then you can do whatever you wish with grouping.  If you actually do still have some summarizing to do, do so ahead of time on your own.

```
proc sgplot data=_test3 ;
  vbarparm category=Day response=DailySales/group=dow barwidth=0.7 nooutline;
  series x=day y=WeeklySales;
  keylegend / position=topright noborder autoitemsize;
  xaxis display=(nolabel);
  yaxis grid;
run;
```